# Running npm on PowerShell asks "How do you want to open this file?", command line is fine

Tags: node.js, windows, powershell, npm

Whenever I run the npm command on Microsoft Windows PowerShell, it opens the Windows 10 popup asking What do you want to do with this file?... what do I want to open it with?

[image: Here is a screen shot]

But I can run node -v and it works fine. This means that I cannot do an "& npm install" from PowerShell to make it run cmd and that command.

Any ideas? I've looked around and no success...

Comment: Does the problem still occur when u open a new powershell instance? Have you tried restarting your computer and see if the problem still occurs. You could try reinstalling node again.

Comment: Thank you, reinstalling node worked!

Answer (score 28):

In powershell run the command "get-command npm"

It may give you the wrong path.

I was getting the same error and the command told me it was finding npm in  C:\WINDOWS\system32\npm

which was a 0 byte file. I deleted it and powershell now found the right path for npm.

Comment: Initially when I got this error "gcm npm" showed the correct path. I tried reinstalling node, but still had the same problem. But this time it found a 0 byte npm file in system32. Now when I deleted that file, npm worked. Another interesting fact is that npm always worked for me in a standard Powershell window. It was only in a PS terminal in VSCode that I got the popup box asking how to open the file.

Comment: this was the cause of my errors, after deleting the file powershell finally used the path location. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the solution its working for me after deleting the 0 byte file (npm).

Comment: had the same with pnpm after removing and reinstalling it via npm. I wonder what caused it (I mean, I know what, but why)

Answer (score 5):

Delete the 0 byte file
path: C:\WINDOWS\system32\npm right click on npm and delete it.

Comment: What is with this creating empty files thing? There aren't too many threads regarding this, but enough so that there should be an explanation already. Just had this issue with the command "py", and, as now expected, and for absolutely no apparent reason, the empty "py" file was in the System32 folder.

Answer (score 0):

This could be because your npm.cmd is missing in the nodejs folder(C:\Program Files\nodejs). Try reinstalling Node from https://nodejs.org/en/download and npm commands will start to work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKuEc.png)